# wsdl creation to connect facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, wsdl

I am new to facebook graph api. I have gone through the restfb client which uses graph api to connect facebook. It has publish,fetching objects methods etc.

I am in need of creating a wsdl in order to connect and upload a photo in facebook from outside?

How can i create a wsdl which should have an interface to connect and upload photo in facebook?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create wsdl to access facebook using Graph API](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11034925/how-to-create-wsdl-to-access-facebook-using-graph-api)

Answer (score 1):

Facebook exposes its webservices through RESTfull webservice.

RESTfull webservices typically don't have a wsdl file where you can directly create a client.

But facebook does provide client library in many popular languages you can use any of those to connect to facebook.

RESTfull webservices are also easy to use. You can also make REST calls directly without any library. Like curl in php. HTTPUrlConnection in Java.